# Creating class instances

Tags: python

Could someone please explain to me how to create class instances from a list (or a string that might be fetched from excel). I always seem to run into this problem. I want to create many instances of classes and then save them in a shelve later.

This sample code doesn't work, but illustrates the approach I'm trying.

```
class test:
  def __init__(self):
      self.a='name'

if _name__=='__main__':
   list=['A','B']
   for item in list:
       item=test()
```

Comment: When you call "for i in seq:", the i isn't the original object in seq, but a copy to it. So your code wouldn't work.

Comment: Why are you trying this?  Where have you seen `class` used as a function?  What tutorial are you following to learn Python?

Comment: Sorry all, new to python and new to Stackoverflow. Please excuse my struggles.

Comment: I know that that if I type A=test() A will be an instance of test, and A.a='name'. In my program, the name of the class instance will be entered by the user (in excel) and I need to create the class instance from this string value.

Comment: I cannot recall one point in time from when I first started programming to now where I though that it was a good idea to have the name of an instance be dependent upon what should be an instance variable. If you have a class to keep track of users, name it `User`. An instance could be `user` or `active_user` or `banned_user` etc. There's __no good__ reason for the an instance to be named `fred`.

Comment: The program I'm writing gets values from excel that are entered by the user. These values are used to compute an Nth order polynomial and write x/y values back to excel. In this process, the user will also enter a name that will be used to create an instance of the poly solving class. This name should be unique to the user such that it helps them to recognize what instance they're creating. Could be Fred if they chose. Why should the code care?

Comment: @Todd: You changed the code dramatically.  Please don't do that.  Please close the question rather than totally rewrite the code sample.  You've made all the comments incomprehensible.  How about closing this question and opening your **real** question with a better code sample and a better explanation for what you're **really** trying to do?

Comment: @Kabie: it's not really a copy; it's a reference to the item in the list. The real problem is that the assignment 'item = test()' does not modify the referred-to list item; instead, it causes 'item' to stop referring to the list item and start referring to the new test instance.

Comment: @S.Lott: I currently cannot close this question. I simply want to accept input from a user, and create a class instance using this input. From above.....(user input)=test(). I want the class instance to exist by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Few issues in your code includes naming of variables. It can confuse you.

```
class test:
    # I guess you want to provide the name to initialize the object attribute
    def __init__(self, name):   
        # self.name is the attribute where the name is stored.
        # I prefer it to self.A 
        self.name = name
```

Now the issue here is that instance is also a element of your list, which I presume is a name.

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    # I presume these are list of names
    list_of_names = ['A','b','c']

    # You have to store your instance some where.
    instance_list = []

    # Here name is an element of the list that you are iterating
    # I change it to name instead of instance
    for name in list_of_names:   
        # Here I am appending to the list, a test object that I create         
        instance_list.append(test(name))
```

[Edit:]

Now, I truly don't understand you, why this piece of code:

```
  for item in list:
       item=class()   # How can you reassign the item ?
```

See what this item is .

```
>>> for item in ['A', 'B']:
...     print item
... 
A
B
>>>
```

You should not assign it `item = ....` but you should use it `.... = ..(item)` !!!

Comment: Each class instance will get variables from somewhere else and perform functions. What I'm stuck on is how to create instances from a fetched string value (or a list as in this case)

Comment: @Todd: what does "create instances *from a fetched string value* __mean__? Instances aren't created __from__ anythin.